# Ember: Specify a target action view for an action helper, other than the containing or parent view

Tags: events, ember.js, ember.js-view

In Ember, if you want an action to be handled by a view, it's easy to achieve this using

```
<button {{action 'something' target='view'}}>
`{{view App.targetView}}` // this is the view in which the 'something' action ought to be handled
```

If you wanted the parentView to handle this, then `target='view'` gets replaced with `target='parentView'`

Fair enough, my problem is that I want a childView to handle and simply stating 'childView' yields

**'Cannot read property 'send' of undefined '**

I could choose to specify the name of the view in here, like :

```
target='targetView'
```

where

```
{{view App.targetView viewName="targetView"}}
```

that did not work. Neither did

```
target ='views.targetView' nor 'childViews.targetView'
```

Please don't guide me to change the semantic structure of my app by stating that the button with this action needs to be within the App.targetView template because that to me is a hack and messing with the semantic structure of my app.

What I do need to know is how I can use the target property to specify a specific view, not just the containing or parent view :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest, my instinctive response is "eek, don't do that". But, I'm going to suspend disbelief and stipulate that you have a good reason for wanting to do this.

The reason your approach did not work is that the `target` property path is evaluated in the template's context (which by default is the controller). Solution: use the `view` keyword in the property path and chain the viewName of the target view.

e.g.

```
<button {{action "foo" target="view.targetView"}}>Click me</button>
{{view App.TargetView viewName="targetView"}}
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aGagORaz/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yea I totally do, the buttons exist outside of the view. But they manipulate this specific view, trying to have them within this view itself challenges my semantic sensibilities

Comment: If the button exists outside the view, have it send an action up to a controller that the views share access to. The action handled in the controller would update a property that the view would then respond to accordingly. e.g. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/aGagORaz/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: you feel that is a better strategy than simply having the button specify which view it is supposed to manipulate?  It feels a little bit of an overkill sending an action request to a controller when it is really just a pure view response.

Comment: IMO, controllers don't know anything about views, so sending an action to be handled by the controller which in turn passes on the action to one of it's views is just counter intuitive. Also, your solution works fine if one is a childView of the other, but not if the aren't

Comment: just figured this, I did this view.parentView.targetView in my button action target attribute. Worked :)

Comment: Sending up to a controller and letting the result of a property change flows down means that your views remain decoupled from each other, and in particular, view hierarchy can be changed without a problem. Just cleaner and more maintainable, IMO.

Comment: Oh yes, definitely agreeing with that.